# Close one accordion when another is open

Tags: angular, typescript

I have tried a custom accordion where the first one is by default open when the page loads. There are 3 accordions in totality. I have to close an accordion when the other one is open.

I have tried giving a custom class like "active" to be attached to the accordions which are closed. The content for the accordion is coming from the API

```
      <div class="card-accordion">
        <div
          class="card"
          *ngFor="let q of popUpContent?.questions; let i = index"
        >
          <div
            class="card-header"
            id="headingOne"
            type="button"
            data-toggle="collapse"
            [attr.data-target]="'#collapse' + i"
            [attr.aria-expanded]="i == 0 ? true : false"
            aria-controls="collapseOne"
          >
          </div>

          <div
            id="collapse{{ i }}"
            class="collapse"
            [ngClass]="{ in: i == 0 }"
            aria-labelledby="headingOne"
            data-parent="#accordionExample"
          >
            <div class="card-body">{{ q.description }}</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I expect that one accordion closes when the other one opens, but the actual output is that when i open the other accordion the previous one doesnt close

Comment: You have a lot of code here. Can you please remove the code that is not related to the open-close action of the accordian? It would help us better understand your problem.

Comment: I have updated the code please check

Comment: You have also not completed your last sentence. However I have posted the solution I would use to achieve the required functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple accordion solution using `*ngIf`. You can use `<div>` tags instead of all the custom selectors in the template code below but I would advise against that as it is detrimental to the understandability of the code.

**accordion.component.ts**

```
class AccordionComponent {
  activeAccordion = 'One'

  isActive = (name: string) => this.activeAccordion === name

  setActive = (name: string) => this.activeAccordion = name
}
```

**accordion.component.html**

```
  <accordion-item title="Accordion One" [ngClass]="{ 'active': isActive('One') }" (click)="setActive('One')" >  
    <accordion-content *ngIf="isActive('One')"> ... </accordion-content>
  </accordion-item>

  <accordion-item title="Accordion Two" [ngClass]="{ 'active': isActive('Two') }" (click)="setActive('Two')" >
    <accordion-content *ngIf="isActive('Two')"> ... </accordion-content>
  </accordion-item>

  <accordion-item title="Accordion Three" [ngClass]="{ 'active': isActive('Three') }" (click)="setActive('Three')" >
    <accordion-content *ngIf="isActive('Three')"> ... </accordion-content>
  </accordion-item>
```

Working solution on StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b57ybp

Comment: Appreciate your effort but not working in my case though

Answer (score 2):

A suggestion I can come up is:

Try adding a variable from typescript end with default value = index of the accordion with you want to be opened by default

```
currentAccordionindex = 0
```

Then apply 'active' class you mentioned(which I hope is to toggle betwwen opened and closed state of the accordion) like:

```
[ngClass]="currentAccordionindex === i ? 'active':'' "
```

Update this value for currentAccordionindex  using (click) event upon the accordion.

Comment: Appreciate your effort  but doesnt seem to be working as intended